# python def create_file_if_not_exist(file_name: str): SyntaxError: invalid syntax near colon

Tags: python, debugging

```
File "report.py", line 17
12:05:47      def create_file_if_not_exist(file_name: str):
12:05:47                                            ^
12:05:47  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm getting this error when I run python report.py

Can someone help me find out what m i doing wrong

I tried removing : str from "def create_file_if_not_exist(file_name: str)"but the error passes to next line

```
def set_logging():
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.INFO,
        format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
        handlers=[
            logging.FileHandler("debug.log"),
            logging.StreamHandler()])

def create_file_if_not_exist(file_name: str):
    if (not path.exists(f'{sys.path[0]}/{file_name}')):
        logging.info(f'{sys.path[0]}/{file_name} not exist.')
        data_file = open(f'{sys.path[0]}/{file_name}', 'w+')
        csv_writer = csv.writer(data_file)
        values = ["Date", "Test Level","Total","Fail","Pass","Elapsed","Jenkins Build","Pass%","Build URL"]
        
        csv_writer.writerow(values)
        logging.info("Header added to the file")
        data_file.close()
        logging.info(f'{sys.path[0]}/{file_name} created.')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        set_logging()
    
        logging.info("---- Fetching csv file ----")
        file_name = "report_FT.csv"
        create_file_if_not_exist(file_name)
        data_file = open(f'{sys.path[0]}/{file_name}', 'a')
        csv_writer = csv.writer(data_file)
```

Comment: It look OK. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @Mureinik it's Python 2.7.13, I can't update since the whole project works on this version updating can effect things sadly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `: str` you're seeing there is a [type hint](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/), introduced in Python 3.5.

If you cannot upgrade your project to use (at least) Python 3.5 (which is understandable, it's not a trivial upgrade from 2.7.13), you could just remove these hints:

```py
def create_file_if_not_exist(file_name):
    # Type hint removed here ---------^
```